# Missing iMovies

Tags: imovie

my macbook air had problems earlier, so I later had to reboot it. Then I had to accept it through Macintosch. Afterwards, my laptop started working and I found my iMovies app missing. how am i able to get the iMovies app back without purchasing it back?

Answer (score 1):

Launch App Store.
It should show as already purchased.

Make sure you are signed in, from the Store menu.

BTW, did you check the Applications folder to make sure it's not just the Dock icon that's missing? If that's the case you can just drag iMove to the Dock & it will make a new link.